# How to flash without STLINK

Tags: stm32, bluepill

My STLINKV2 is not working anymore, not detected by Linux, it failed after the first successful flash. I ordered a new one but it will take 60+ days to arrive. Meanwhile I have heard on Youtube you can program Bluepills directly by connecting cut open USB cable to certain pins and then using a jumper. But I cannot get any precie information on this, is this really possible and how?

Comment: Here is one of those videos that mention flashing without the programmer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1r_Pyyc_6e8

Comment: There are loads of STLINKV2 and V3 available for immediate dispatch on the web. Also you can use the STLINK on any Nucleo board as a stand alone STLINK (details available in the Nucleo documentation).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the embedded bootloader. You can flash it through several interfaces. Look at [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594.pdf), <s>maybe you can find an already written flasher. Good luck</s> STM32CubeProgrammer handle it.

If you intend to program it through usb, look also at [AN3156](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00264379.pdf) all protocols document are referred in chapter 2 of [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**THOSE AREN'T CUT OPEN USB CABLES** they are USB to serial adapters for arduino's bootloader
[image: usb serial cable]

They connect them like this:[image: stm blue pill programming]

The problem is that this requires the Arduino STM32 bootloader to be flashed in it.

Another option will be to use [STM32CubeProg](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) this program allows you to program your stm over

- Serial
- SPI
- I2C
- USB

You'll need to set the `BOOT0` and `BOOT1` pins to the correct value (`HIGH` slash `LOW`) to allow it to go in flash mode during boot.
[Here](http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/09/program-stm32f4-with-uart/) is semi outdated tutorial which tells most of the steps to program a STM using serial. (the `Flash Loader Demonstrator` is outdated and you should use STM32CubeProg)